# How to convert an Array of Arrays of strings to an Array of Arrays of numbers?

Tags: angular, typescript, turfjs

I have an Array of Arrays of strings like below:

```
 [    
 0: Array(1)
    0: Array(6)
        0:  [5.379856, 43.252967]
        1:  [5.422988, 43.249466]
        2:  [5.425048, 43.245153]
        3:  [5.383804, 43.239838]
        4:  [5.399856, 43.212967]
        5:  [5.379856, 43.252967]
1: Array(1)
    0: Array(6)
        0:  [5.39014, 43.279295]
        1:  [5.393069, 43.279249]
        2:  [5.391814, 43.278421]
        3:  [5.390709, 43.278749]
        4:  [5.3909, 43.2785]
        5:  [5.39014, 43.279295]
 ]
```

The values are strings. I would like to convert each value into a number.
Can someone explain how can this be done without a loop please?

Kind Regards,

Comment: as a short comment, not a full answer, you can "cast" a string to a number in JS / TS by just adding a "plus" `+` sign in front of them.  `+"12" === 12` or `const a: string = "12"; const b: number = +a;`

Comment: Unless you've removed every quote from the console output your arrays have only numbers and not strings

Comment: Is there a practical reason you don't want a loop? Also, please show [any attempt you've made to solve this yourself](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have numbers in the array not strings. But if you have strings, you can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Number()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) to convert them to numbers.

```js
var data = [
  [
    ["5.379856", "43.252967"],
    ["5.422988", "43.249466"],
    ["5.425048", "43.245153"],
    ["5.383804", "43.239838"],
    ["5.399856", "43.212967"],
    ["5.379856", "43.252967"]
  ],
  [
    ["5.39014", "43.279295"],
    ["5.393069", "43.279249"],
    ["5.391814", "43.278421"],
    ["5.390709", "43.278749"],
    ["5.3909", "43.2785"],
    ["5.39014", "43.279295"]
  ]
];

data = data.map(arr => arr.map(item => item.map(value => Number(value))));

console.log(data);
```